# no overload for matches delegate func<T, T>

Tags: c#

I have some problem with delegates

My scheme of classes:

```
public interface IWorker<T> where T : IModel
{     
   T Do(T model);
   T ReadyToWork(T model);
}

public abstract class Workers<T> : IWorker<T> where T : IModel
{
   public abstract T Do(T model);
   public abstract T ReadyToWork(T model);
}
```

Class to work! `FirstModel : IModel`

```
public class FirstWorker : Workers<ModelFirst>
{
   public override ModelFirst Do(ModelFirst model)
   {
      return new ModelUserFirst();
   }
   public override ModelFirst ReadyToWork(ModelFirst model)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

I can create many work specials classes, and to work with them I created one access point:

```
public class WorkPoint<T> where T : IModel
{
    public static Func<T, T> Do { get; set; }
    public static Func<T, T> ReadyToWork{ get; set; }

    public WorkPoint(ModelFirst mod)
    {
       Do = FirstWorker.Instance().Do;
       ReadyToWork= FirstWorker.Instance().ReadyToWork;
    }
}
```

ok, and question. on moment assignments `Do` and `ReadyToWork` I catching error 
*Error  CS0123  No overload for 'Do' matches delegate 'Func'*
Whats wrong?

Comment: In these situations, the quickest way to figure out what's going on is to try assigning it to a variable that doesn't exist, then use Quick Actions and Refactorings to create the variable for you.  You'll then see the actual signature of the variable and generally be able to figure out why what you were trying to do was failing.

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] here - we can't see `UserFirstWorker` or its `Instance` method for example. But if it's a `FirstWorker` or similar, what would you expect to happen if someone used `WorkPoint<SomeOtherModel>`?

Comment: This looks like you want to use covariance.  `Func<T, T>` is only covariant on the second`T`, but contravariant on the first, meaning the `Do` method has to match `T` exactly.

Comment: @juharr Can I get around this?

Comment: I'd say you'd need to reconsider your design, I cannot really say how as I'm not sure the underlying problem you are trying to solve with this code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, but this works:

```
public class WorkPoint<T> where T : IModel
{
    public Func<T, T> Do { get; }
    public Func<T, T> ReadyToWork { get; }

    protected WorkPoint(Func<T, T> f, Func<T, T> r)
    {
        Do = f;
        ReadyToWork = r;
    }
}

// Create a simple class like this for evert worker type you need
public class FirstWorkPoint : WorkPoint<ModelFirst>
{
    private FirstWorkPoint() :
        base(FirstWorker.Instance().Do, FirstWorker.Instance().ReadyToWork)
    { }

    // Public method to get a new base instance
    public static WorkPoint<ModelFirst> New() => new FirstWorkPoint();
}
```

This will add a bit of overhead due to the additional class created, but it should act as a workaround for that covariance issue being pointed out in the comments.

This way you could just do:

```
WorkPoint<ModelFirst> point = FirstWorkPoint.New();
```

**Edit**: Also, if you don't need that base `Workers<T>` class I'd say you could just get rid of it and have the actual worker classes directly inherit from your interface. After all, the base class doesn't provide any additional functionalities in the above code.

Comment: in this realization year, but i may have some methodts whith a common realization. And what is `m`? i add this solve to my solution and `m` _does not exist in current context_

Comment: @jailbot Right, sorry, I've updated my answer with a working solution :)

Comment: thanks, but it not possible for my situation, becouse i may have many `Workers` and many `Models`

Comment: Yeah, this was more or less a workaround, since the code you posted can't be compiled due to the way that generic parameter is resolved in the class.
You should consider redesigning the class hierarchy in this situation, as I don't see other possible solutions without changing the code at least a bit.(Also, could you remove the -1 since this code is at least working, even though it still doesn't solve the problem?)